# When you create a file in python, where does it save it?

Tags: python

I have been able to create a file but when I need to be able to access it from elsewhere and not just the programm. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Which IDE or editor did you use?

Comment: I'm assuming python is creating the file?  Can you give the command that you use to open it?

Answer (score 4):

Unless you specify an absolute path, Python will save files in the current working directory - you can easily find out where that is:

```
>>> import os
>>> os.getcwd()
'C:\\Python34'
```

Answer (score 2):

```
import os

fo = open('test.txt', 'w+')
print os.path.abspath(fo.name)
```

it will print something like:

```
C:\Users\member\Desktop\Code\test.txt
```

which is the fullpath to the file that you created.